# simple_format changes the text itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails 3.0, the helper method simple_format changes the parameter itself.
I expected that it only returns the wrapped text.

```
2.0.0-p648 :001 > Rails.version
 => "3.0.20"
2.0.0-p648 :002 > s = "Hello"
 => "Hello"
2.0.0-p648 :003 > helper.simple_format(s)
 => "<p>Hello</p>"
2.0.0-p648 :004 > s
 => "<p>Hello</p>"
```

I checked with Rails 4.2 and it doesn't change the text.

Can someone please explain it?

Sam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between implementations of this method in `Rails 4.2` and `Rails 3.0` is that in `Rails 3.0` the passed string is modified (mutated by `gsub!`) and in `Rails 4.2` it's not (it just returns a new modified string):

`Rails 4.2`:

```
2.4.0 :006 > s = "hello"
 => "hello"
2.4.0 :007 > simple_format s
 => "<p>hello</p>"
2.4.0 :008 > s
 => "hello"
```

The source code of different implementations can be found in the [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/simple_format)

Comment: Thank you, Igor. I can never understand why the old version was designed like that.